# Capture HTML errors with JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics

Is there a way to capture all HTML errors that may occur in a website?

I saw a very interesting article telling how we can track script errors in our sites with Google Analytics and I was wondering if we could use it for HTML errors too.

The link for the article is http://www.dp6.com.br/javascript-debug-simples-com-google-analytics. Sorry for it's in Portuguese, but if you don't speak my language you have Google Translator to help you out ;o)

PS: By HTML errors I mean element rendering errors, 404, 500, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried it?  As far as I know, errors with things loading (scripts, included files, images etc.) should still be flagged as errors in the window object, and it looks like that's all that script is doing.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Archer. I tried it but it doesn't seem to capture any html error. I tried adding an image to my site with an incorrect path and it was not caught up.

Answer (score 0):

use a common js file on all of the pages. Try catching the page headers using js

eg [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: I'll give it a try and return to you. Thanks for replying.